# android animating switching between activities - windows order

Tags: android, animation, window

I'm following this how to [DevBytes: Window Animations](http://youtu.be/Ho8vk61lVIU) to implement translation as an animation when switching between activities.

Everything is working fine except animation when user presses back button from SUBACTIVITY to go to MAIN ACTIVITY. When MAIN ACTIVITY slides in it is **under** the SUBACTIVITY and i would like it be **on top** of it.

I use `overridePendingTransition()` to create animation when user goes back to MAIN ACTIVITY.

```java
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

slide_in_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="3500" /> 
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="50%p"
        android:duration="3500" />
</set>
```

How can i reorder windows during animation so MAIN ACTIVITY is on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question. I was able to get my animation working smoothly and looking nice using the following animations with `overridePendingTransition()` in the sub-activity's `finish()`:

slide_in_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="300" />
```

slide_out_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="300" />
```